# Flattening a heavily nested JSON in Java - Time Complexity

Tags: java, json, spring, spring-boot, jackson

```
{
  "id": "12345678",
  "data": {
    "address": {
      "street": "Address 1",
      "locality": "test loc",
      "region": "USA"
    },
    "country_of_residence": "USA",
    "date_of_birth": {
      "month": 2,
      "year": 1988
    },
    "links": {
      "self": "https://testurl"
    },
    "name": "John Doe",
    "nationality": "XY",
    "other": [
      { 
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2
      },
      { 
        "key1": "value1",
        "key2": "value2"
      }
    ],
    "notified_on": "2016-04-06"
  }
}
```

I am trying to read data from a GraphQL API that returns paginated JSON response. I need to write this into a CSV. I have been exploring Spring Batch for implementation where I would read JSON data in the ItemReader and flatten each JSON entry (in ItemProcessor) and then write this flattened data into a CSV (in ItemWriter). While I could use something like Jackson for flattening the JSON, I am concerned about possible performance implications if the JSON data is heavily nested.

**expected output:**

```
id, data.address.street, data.address.locality, data.address.region, data.country_of_residence, data.date_of_birth.month, data.date_of_birth.year, data.links.self, data.name, data.nationality, data.other (using jsonPath), data.notified_on
```

I need to do process more than a million records. While I believe flattening the CSV would be a linear operation O(n), I was still wondering if there could be other caveats if the JSON structure gets severely nested.

Comment: I don't personally get how do you write this in CSV, and why are you concerned with time complexity. What's the expected input "record", and what's the output record? Are you just writing out all the name-value pairs? How would you write out the contents of `others` property? Using JSONPath? Something else?

Comment: I am basically trying to read data from a GraphQL API and write it into a CSV. Since, the nature of the graphql response is a severely nested JSON (also more than a million records), I feel flattening it would could cause performance issues.

Comment: It would cause no more performance issues than simply parsing it as JSON, unless you insist on keeping the whole CSV in an extremely inefficient container object. If you parse as it comes in and then write to a file right away, then it doesn't matter how many records are there.